# Galois invariant of Tate twists

Tags: prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

let $k$ be the maximal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ unramified outside a set $T$ of primes in $\mathbb{Z}$. 
Take a $p\in T$ and set $G=Gal(k/\mathbb{Q})$. I would like to now if there is a classical result in order to compute the cohomology group $H^0(G,\mathbb{Q}_p(n))$ for $n\geq 1$?

Comment: What do you mean by $Q_p(n)$? Are they $\pi^n$-th division field extensions? And is $T$ finite? Also, what have you tried? And what do you know about the subject? Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: @awllower $T$ is finite. Actually I would like to use $H^i(G,\mathbb{Q}_p(n))=H_{et}^i(Spec(\mathcal{O}_F[\frac{1}{p}]),\mathbb{Q}_p(n)):= \lim_m H_{et}^i(Spec(\mathcal{O}_F[\frac{1}{p}]),\mu_{p^m}^{\otimes n})\otimes \mathbb{Q}_p$. I would like to know if the previous isomorphism is true and if one can compute such groups

Comment: @awllower you can assume $H^i(G,\mu_{p^m}^{\otimes n})$

Comment: @awllower I'm not sure what the complaint is. The notation is quite standard, and anyone who understands the question enough to have a chance at answering it will know what it means.

Comment: @Matt Sorry. It was my fault.I have deleted the previous comment.Thanks.